# Is BreezeJS ready to work with angular 2 or will updates be needed?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Is BreezeJS ready to work with angular 2 or will updates be needed?  Are there different nuget packages or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to Ward last solution [Breeze with angular 2](https://t.co/XnXSTQ730G)

and you can do your best.